# Dependency property not updating Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, dependency-properties

I'm having some trouble updating a dependency property of a UserControl/View.

I have a main view (MainView.xaml) that has a series of other user controls declared inside it. One of them looks as follows:

```
<local:Snapshot BrandID="{Binding Path=Session.Test}" />
```

My Snapshot.xaml has a a TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Text="Sample text" x:Name="brandIDTBlock" />
```

And my Snapshot.xaml.cs has the following dependency property:

```
public string BrandID
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(BrandIdProperty); }
    set { SetValue(BrandIdProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty BrandIdProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BrandID", typeof(string), typeof(Snapshot), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnBrandIdChange)));

private static void OnBrandIdChange(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = (Snapshot)d;
    control.brandIDTBlock.Text = (string)e.NewValue;
}
```

Session is a property of the MainView and I want my brandIDTBlock TextBlock to be updated when the Test property is changed in the Session object.

The Test property is declared like so:

```
private string _test = "Test Value Binding";

public string Test 
{
    get { return _test; }
    set { _test = value; } 
}
```

Right now somehting is working as when I run the app I see "Test Value Binding" correctly being displayed in my view, the problem is that when the value of Test changes in my Session object the change does not propagate to the view.

I also tried to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface like so:

```
public string Test
{
    get { return _test; }
    set
    {
        _test = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Test");
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

but it's still not updating.

UPDATE: It turns out that it was a nooby mistake, again. In my Snapshot.xaml.cs I was changing the data context in a piece code that handled a pie chart. I worked around it by changing my binding epression in so that the binding element would be the parent of Snapshot.xaml, in my case the StackPanel 'sp' ({Binding ElementName=sp, Path=DataContext.Session.Test}). Apart from this silly mistake, what was really missing from my original code was the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation, TwoWay binding was unnecessary.

Thanks

Luis

Comment: Thats a well structured question, however have you actually added to the `INotifyPropertyChanged` to the `class Session` declaration line?

Comment: Yes, Session implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `Mode=TwoWay` to your binding:

```
<local:Snapshot BrandID="{Binding Path=Session.Test, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

`OneWay` is the default and that allows the UI to update the bound value only. To get the UI to change after the bound value is changed you need `TwoWay`.

You also need to raise the property changed event to let the UI know that something has changed.

The only other thing is to check that you've set the `DataContext` of your view up correctly.

Comment: TwoWay binding is not needed here. TwoWay would be used if a `TextBox` were being used and it was desirable for the user to be able to change the value by typing a new one.  The default OneWay binding is fine in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The binding is not correct. By using a {Binding} with just a path you try to bind to the data exposed through the DataContext. Did you set the DataContext?

**EDIT**

There is more wrong in your code:

`control.brandIDTBlock.Text = (string)e.NewValue;`

This line does not belong in the PropertyChanged handler. And might cause you to think that binding is working.

I do not have the time to add a correct example so [here is a link that should get you started.](http://odetocode.com/code/740.aspx)

Comment: In that case even the original value would not show up, the problem is that a change in the value is not propergating.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to set the DataContext, but this is the way it actually works, I have a Column class which has a DataTemplate ContentTemplate which returns the my MainView.xaml (similarly it has a header, this part works), it is the Column class which has a reference to my Session object. So when I say Session.Text in my MainView it gets the Session object form my Column class and tries to read its Test property. The MainView uses another control inside it (Snapshot) and in that control's .cs file I have my dependency property that needs updating. Where should I set the data context?

Comment: There is more wrong in your code. It looks like you are not understanding the concepts and responsibilities yet. So I added a link to a tutorial in my answer.

Comment: Again I don't agree that line looks fine to me.

Comment: @ AnthonyWJones: Noted. I don't like that line because it adds an unexpected dependency that normally is created through a binding.

Answer (score 0):

When the value of `Test` changes in your view model is it "changing" because you have replaced the object being returned the the `Session` property of your main view model.  If so you would need the main view model to alse implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and call PropertyChanged when the Session property is updated.